# Why does Mathematica spit this back out?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm struggling with the integral,
$$\iint\sqrt{4a^2-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$
taken over the upper half disk of radius a centered at (a, 0).

When I type it into *Mathematica* (10.2), *Mathematica* spits it back out.
Here's my code.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[4a^2-x^2-y^2]Boole[x^2+y^2<2a x], {x, 0, 2a}, {y, 0, a}]
```

The output *Mathematica* produces is just the fancy version (2 dimensional) of this. This integration is easy, I've even done it by hand. Why can't *Mathematica* do it?

Comment: You could put a `Assumptions -> a > 0` as an option.

Comment: Well, unlike *Mathematica*, you assume that $a$ is real and positive, no? (Thus, follow wxffles's suggestion.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As J.M. noted, when you do it by hand, you presume that you are working with real variables and, probably, that `a > 0`. *Mathematica* doesn't make such assumptions by default, so you need to give it a hint.

For example,

```
Integrate[Sqrt[4 a^2 - x^2 - y^2] Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 2 a x], 
  {x, 0, 2 a}, {y, 0, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

will give

```
4/9 a^3 (-4 + 3 π)
```

which is perhaps what you are expecting.

Another way of writing this integral in *Mathematica* is

```
Integrate[Sqrt[4 a^2 - x^2 - y^2], 
  {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 2 a x && y > 0, {x, y}]]
```

Here the necessary assumptions are implicit in the region expression and a more complete answer is given.

[image: result]

Answer (score 7):

This gives the result without assumptions:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[4 a^2 - x^2 - y^2] , Element[{x, y},
  RegionIntersection[Disk[{a, 0}, a], ImplicitRegion[y > 0, {x, y}]]]]
```

> Piecewise[{{(4*a^3*(-4 + 3*Pi))/9, a > 0}}, 0]

(A little bit faster than the `Boole` approach as well )

Answer (score 2):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(x - a)^2 + y^2 <= a^2 && 0 <= y <= a, {x, y}]
Integrate[Sqrt[4*a^2 - x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Assumptions -> a > 0]

4/9 a^3 (-4 + 3 Pi)
```

Interestingly, this should also work, but it runs forever!

```
reg = Disk[{a, 0}, a, {0, Pi}]
Integrate[Sqrt[4*a^2 - x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer; merely an observation.